# Edge lines don't show up in Cytoscape.js graph in Chrome for Android

Tags: javascript, android, cytoscape.js, chrome-for-android

When I open a [cytoscape.js](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/) graph in Chrome for Android, the edge lines do not show up regardless of what line thickness is used.

Here is an example:
http://jsbin.com/AnEtura/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Cy.js uses the standard canvas API for drawing.  It seems like it works everywhere else, so I suspect the issue may be Chrome.

I don't have access to an Android device, so would you be able to tell me...

- Are there any error messages?
- Does canvas line drawing work on Android?
- Does canvas bezier curve drawing work on Android?
- etc

Comment: I do see this message: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. It looks like Chrome for Android has full canvas support according to this: http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas.

Comment: jQuery uses that for IE support and the event wrapper objects have them (since those objects are copied from jquery), but it's not used in cy.js itself.

Comment: There may be another issue, but event.returnValue is not it.